# What is the key difference between a Web application and a Web Portal?

Tags: comparison

I taught i had a clear view of the difference between these, but giving it a deep i got confused.

Can someone help with a comparison, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A web application offers a clear and focused service. A web portal is rather a sort of "start page" that contains links to a variety of resources and services. See here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_portal

Comment: hummm! That was quite precise. So a portal is not an application, it is an implementation.

Comment: A portal is sort of a "meta-application", which offers links to other applications.

Answer (score 1):

A portal server is a portlet container for deploying a range of applications as individual portlets. The server does the authorization, authentication and generic housekeeping, routing user queries to appropriate portlets. In contrast, web servers focus on serving web pages and web applications serve single applications. Portal servers adhere to JSR and WSRP standards.

Answer (score 1):

Web application is the one which is deployed on a public network and can be accessed by user over intranet or internet.

A web portal is the one which is a collection of sites and unique services, which is created to provide complete information to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a web portal is a single access point to various kinds of information provided by a company. That information can be categorized and accessed by certain links. For example, a web portal will let you access company articles, information related to products, or even vendors or suppliers lists. Here's a [good research](https://gbksoft.com/blog/web-portal-development-costs/) on this topic.